# Rails SQL Query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

In the following block of code, on what line is the SQL actually executed on the database?

```
first_name, last_name = @name.split(", ")
people = Person.where(first_name: first_name)
people = people.limit(5)
people.each do |person|
  puts person
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL query is executed in `people.each do |person|` line because only then Rails need the result of this query. Rails execute SQL only when it's literally needed, not when you build your scope. It's called [lazy loading](http://rubyinrails.com/2014/01/08/what-is-lazy-loading-in-rails/).

Comment: But should it be in line 2 and line 3. Can you explain your answer pls.

Comment: I edited my answer. No, it should not be in line 2 and line 3 because rails don't need the result of this query in these lines.